# missing FROM-clause in posgressql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm facing the below error while executing the below SQL statement in Django after converting from sqlite to postgressql, it was working fine with sqlite.

```
         joined_data = HistoryTable.objects.raw(

        '''
        SELECT pages_historytable.id, pages_historytable.dial, pages_historytable.request_status, pages_historytable.summary, pages_historytable.registration_date, dashboard_storesemails.emails, dashboard_storescode.agent_name
        FROM pages_historytable
        LEFT JOIN dashboard_storescode
        ON pages_historytable.dial = dashboard_storescode.dial
        LEFT JOIN dashboard_storesmails
        ON dashboard_storescode.shop_code = dashboard_storesmails.dtscode
        WHERE pages_historytable.request_status = 'Rejected' AND pages_historytable.Today_Date =  %s;
        
        ''',[today])
```

The error is

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "dashboard_storesemails"
LINE 2: ...le.summary, pages_historytable.registration_date, dashboard_...
```

Comment: You use two different spellings for the table `dashboard_storesemails` and `dashboard_storesmails` - why not use the ORM, this query would be a lot simpler and this kind of mistake would happen less often

Comment: It consumes too much time